# Google Map API v2 Heatmap not showing all locations

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, heatmap

I'm trying out the Google API V2 Heatmap (Android) which was introduced this february and it's not working entirely. I'm not sure if it's the same problem as [Google Maps API v2 HeatMap Won't Reliably Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035863/google-maps-api-v2-heatmap-wont-reliably-display) (and I can't contact him by comments because I don't have enough rep.. :c ).

### Using locations from file

Anyway, what I was trying to do was an App with just a GoogleMap and the same locations as in their guide (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/heatmap) and when I launch it, I can only see 3/5 locations.

I tried adding more points and still, it's consistently not showing them all, but I can't see a pattern or something. The code is the same as in their guide.

```
private void addHeatMap() {
    List<LatLng> list = null;

    // Get the data: latitude/longitude positions of police stations.
    try {
        list = readItems(R.raw.police_stations);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Problem reading list of locations.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    // Create a heat map tile provider, passing it the latlngs of the police stations.
    mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
            .data(list)
            .build();
    // Add a tile overlay to the map, using the heat map tile provider.
    mOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));

}


    private ArrayList<LatLng> readItems(int resource) throws JSONException {
        ArrayList<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(resource);
        String json = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
            double lat = object.getDouble("lat");
            double lng = object.getDouble("lng");
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);              
            list.add(latLng);

        }
        return list;
    }
```

Trying with weighted locations had the same result, some of them showing and some not.

### Using locations "onClick"

In this case, normal LatLng were added and the map was updated until I got to the equator and then it stopped :p.

For the case of weightedLatLngs, it didn't update/show any :(

---

That's basically it... I don't know where to look for more information, whether it's something with the API, the device or something else.

Does anyone know why this might happen and/or where to look for a solution ?

Thank you in advance !

Btw, I'm using Android 4.0.4 on a Samsung Galaxy S Duos if that may prove useful..

Comment: Did you manage to find any solution to this? I'm running the latest version of Maps and I'm not getting any heatmap visible.

Comment: I'm not working on it anymore but I didn't manage to solve it back then I remember...

Answer (score 0):

The Googlemaps API for Heatmap only allows for 1,000 plotted points. You can reduced that by filtering out your original data or by converting to "weighted locations".

Comment: The problem is I only have a bunch of points (less than 20) and it's still having problems with it... I don't know why I feel it has to do with the phones android version :/..

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it was caused by [this bug](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/71), where bounds calculations were excluding max values.

This is now fixed.